How to access pod metadata in a later step without using the Argo daemon container feature?
When using Argo daemon containers, referencing the IP of a previous step is well-supported via the {{steps.<step-name>.ip}} variable:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: sidecar-nginx-
spec:
  entrypoint: sidecar-nginx-example
  templates:
  - name: sidecar-nginx-example
    steps:
      - - name: start-nginx
          template: nginx-daemon
      - - name: curl-nginx
          template: curl-container
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: nginx-ip
                value: "{{steps.start-nginx.ip}}"

  - name: nginx-daemon
    daemon: true
    retryStrategy:
      limit: 3
    container:
      name: nginx
      image: nginx:1.13
      command: [nginx, -g, "daemon off;"]
    nodeSelector:
      kubernetes.io/os: linux

  - name: curl-container
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: nginx-ip
    container:
      image: appropriate/curl
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["until `curl -G 'http://{{inputs.parameters.nginx-ip}}/' >& /tmp/out`; do echo sleep && sleep 1; done && cat /tmp/out"]
    nodeSelector:
      kubernetes.io/os: linux

However, when not using formal daemon containers, the convenient {{steps.<step-name>.ip}} variable is not available. So I'm looking for any way to access pod metadata (IP or name) in later workflow steps, while the first step continues to run (nginx or similar).
The following approach works for a terminating first-step workflow (echo some output):
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: pod-name-passing-example-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
  - name: main
    steps:
    - - name: get-pod-name
        template: get-pod-name
    - - name: use-pod-name
        template: use-pod-name
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: pod-name
            value: "{{steps.get-pod-name.outputs.parameters.pod-name}}"

  - name: get-pod-name
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: pod-name
        value: "{{pod.name}}"
    container:
      image: alpine:3.7
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo Capturing pod name"]

  - name: use-pod-name
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: pod-name
    container:
      image: alpine:3.7
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo Step 1 Pod Name is {{inputs.parameters.pod-name}}"]

This workflow is successful because the first step completes, notifying the second step to begin. How would I provide pod metadata to the second step while the first step still runs? Essentially imitating formal daemon container functionality. I've tried various combinations of DAGs, when conditions, wait pattern, and using global parameters. No luck so far.
For reference, the question is motivated by Argo's apparent lack of support for Windows daemon containers. Lastly note that the sidecar pattern is probably not an option, given the server/client containers usually must run in separate pods.

Since this question is about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic for devops.
